# Google Apps Script - Fetch data from third party API with date parameter

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, urlfetch

One of my vendors has created an API that I can use to pull data. I'm trying to use google apps script for this as I can easily schedule the data pull on it.

I've used the UrlFetchApp before but I'm lost with this as I have to pass an additional parameter in it for a date - I don't know how to do this and I would appreciate your help figuring this out.

The instructions given to me are these:

```
url = "https://xxxxx.com/api/leads/"
method = POST
//Request JSON format: (date format should be ‘Y-m-d’)
{"date":"2019-08-21"}
```

In addition to googling, I've tried various iterations of adding the date parameter to the options on UrlFetchApp as well as trying to append it to the URL string.

This is what I have so far:

```
function myFunction() {
  var pullDate = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];  
  var dateParams = {"date": pullDate};
  var url = "https://xxxxx.com/api/leads/";
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "contentType" : "application/json"
  }  

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

This is the response i'm getting:

```
[19-09-09 12:44:36:586 IST] {"result":"date is empty!"}
```

The expected response is something like this:

```
{"result":[
{"count":"55","model":"ABC","date":"2019-09-09"},
{"count":"2","model":"DEF","date":"2019-09-09"},
{"count":"48","model":"XYZ","date":"2019-09-09"}
]}
```

I'd appreciate your help in figuring this out!

Comment: Where is `payload`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to add that. Reading the documentation, it looks like I have to add it in the options variable but I'm not sure what to include in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

- `payload`(or request body) is missing from the request.

#### Snippet:

- You can include `payload` in `options`:

```
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "contentType" : "application/json",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(dateParams)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It worked when i used a JSON stringify with it: "payload": JSON.stringify(dateParams)

Comment: @Abhay Great. Added it to my answer.